# Cannot compile mex file on Windows

Tags: matlab, mex

When I attempt to compile a .mex file on Windows, I get the following error. How can I fix this?

> Error using mex
>
> MEX cannot find library 'mwblas' specified with the -l option.
> MEX looks for a file with one of the names:
> libmwblas.lib
> mwblas.lib
> Please specify the path to this library with the -L option

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, you need to specify the directory in which the `.lib` file is located using the `-L` option or specify the full path to the `.lib` file as an input to `mex`. This library is located in `matlabroot/extern/lib`. So you could do something like

```
blas = fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','lib',computer('arch'),'microsoft', 'libmwblas.lib');
mex('-largeArrayDims', 'mymexfile.cpp', blas)
```

Or you can specify the folder with `-L`

```
libdir = fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','lib',computer('arch'),'microsoft');
mex('-largeArrayDims', ['-L', libdir], '-lmwblas', 'mymexfile.cpp', )
```

More info about compiling mex files to use LAPACK and BLAS is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-lapack-and-blas-functions-from-mex-files.html)